# How to switch to built-in speaks when headphones are plugged in

Tags: macos

I want to be able to switch headphone output to/from built-in speaker output with my mac with software, so that I don't need to do the manual process.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bad news but it's not possible to switch w/o using 3rd party device. There's also a [discussion at apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2609977) with no solution.

Comment: … which 3rd party software would that be?

Comment: Never tried it myself but in the discussion at apple.com they name iMic.

Comment: Only that [iMic](http://store.griffintechnology.com/imic) is not software. It's a USB audio adapter :)

Comment: I didn't take a look at it O:-)